# Function object with numpy fields doesn't compute value when upon function call

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ufunc

I am absolutly new in Python, and I have difficulties using numpy in following way.

My goal is to make a function object which computes `f(input) - g(input)`
I have the following class:

```
class MyFunc:
    def __init__(self, f: callable, g: callable):
        self.f: callable = f
        self.g: callable = g

    def f(self, x: float):
        fresult: float = self.f(x)
        gresult: float = self.g(x)
        result: float = fresult - gresult
        # return self.f(x) - self.g(x)
        return result
```

I am passing numpy functions to object of this class. Like this:

```
import numpy as np
f1 = np.poly1d([0.1381, 0.01081, 0.09903, - 0.9153, - 0.4032])
f2 = np.poly1d([-0.6902, - 0.1294, - 0.1718, - 1.07, 0.1351])

foo = MyFunc(f1, f2)
```

The problem is when I am passing an input to `foo.f`, it computes just `f1(input)` not `f1(input) - f2(input)`

What I have done wrong?

How should I write this correctly?

Here is an example of getting unexpected output:

```
f1 = np.poly1d([0.1381, 0.01081, 0.09903, - 0.9153, - 0.4032])
f2 = np.poly1d([-0.6902, - 0.1294, - 0.1718, - 1.07, 0.1351])

foo = MyFunc(f1, f2)
value: float = -0.41757
r1 = f1(value) # -0.000319....
r2 = f2(value) # 0.54038....
# I expect fresult = result
result = r1 - r2 # -0.5407....
fresult = foo.f(value) # -0.000319....
```

Comment: You used the `f` name for two different things. Pick another name.

Comment: Monica, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your class as:

```
class MyFunc:
    def __init__(self, f: callable, g: callable):
        self.f: callable = f
        self.g: callable = g

    def fn(self, x: float):
        fresult: float = self.f(x)
        gresult: float = self.g(x)
        result: float = fresult - gresult
        return result
```

Note that I changed your *f* function to *fn*, in order to
keep it as a separate object, because you have already *f*
as one of attributes, set in the constructor.

Then call it as:

```
fresult = foo.fn(value)
```

(with the changed function name).

But maybe a simpler approach, without any custom class, is to compute:

```
foo = np.polysub(f1, f2)
result = foo(value)
```

Or even shorter:

```
result = np.polysub(f1, f2)(value)
```

Comment: Vladi_Bo, Thanks a lot.